# measuring microamps Arduino/esp32

Tags: current-measurement, esp32

I have an analogue gauge that works off a 0 to 1mA input. The gauge is for a fuel tank on a ship.

Given the input current is 1 mA at the most, what can I do to make this readable on an esp32?

I tried connecting a resistor in series with the gauge to output a voltage, this worked, but it conflicted with the gauge causing it to be inaccurate. Whatever solution I find, I still need the gauge to retain its accuracy.

I might consider something like INA 219, but don't know if it would work with such small current.

I do not need super high accuracy, the gauge is for a fuel tank on a small ship, and as you can imagine, in any swell, the level is all over the place.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The gauge itself may be the "resistor" in that circuit, with a fixed resistance. Can you measure the voltage across the gauge, and use that as an indicator of current?

Comment: Usually the fuel gauge is a potentiometer moved by a float, with resistance in the 33ohm-240 ohm range. Can you confirm it is a resistive sensor and measure min/max resistance? Is one wire grounded or is it floating? Also the ADC of ESP32 is terrible, if you do not need wifi on your boat I would suggest using another microcontroller with a working ADC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The INA219 has sensitivity of +-40mV at highest gain. Therefore you will need a 40-Ohm shunt to measure your 1mA current with full 12-bit resolution. If you are fine with 10-bit readout, the shunt can be 10 Ohms, and so on. Will the 10-Ohm in-series resistor break your "analog gauge", I don't know.